# How to loop and associate multiple uneven datasets using windows batch

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

EDIT 2.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around loops in windows batch.

I have datasets, and I'm trying to create a one-to-relationship with data in each. However, they aren't equal datasets.

pseudo code would be:

dataset1 \folder\pictures (10 jpgs with random names)

dataset2 db.csv (100 entries in a single column)

Loop through the db.csv, read the first entry and associate it with the first picture. On the 11th entry, begin with the first picture again, etc. (more robust of course, because the datasets aren't fixed amounts)

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in (db.csv) do (
    ren random.jpg pic1-%%a
    ren randomanother.jpg pic2-%%a (2nd entry db.csv)
    ...
    ren random.jpg pic11-%%a (11th entry in db.csv)
    ren randomanother.jpg pic12-%%a (12th entry in db.csv)
    
    etc
    
)
```

I'm NOT looking to use the ren command, it's just an example of how the iteration would work. In the loop, the csv continues reading data, but applies it to the first picture file again.

It's the looping logic that I'm having no success with.

I suspect I might need to count the datasets or at least the pictures dataset to iterate the loops ? The pictures are not numbered sequentially initially, but I can easily rename them to be.

Comment: More information would help get the question answered and keep it from being closed. What does the content of `dataset1` and `dataset2` look like? Are they both CSV files? Is there more than one field in either CSV file? Once `pic1` is RENamed, how are you expecting to REName it again?

Comment: You're not showing the jpg file examples. Do I assume they are `pic1`, `pic2` etc or do I assume random names? How should I know which random file should be `pic1`? etc..

Comment: @Gerhard edited. The command it performs is not as important to me as the logic to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a (pseudo)array of the jpg files for easier handling (so you can keep the random names instead of renaming them consecutively).

Use counters to keep track of which line and which file to process.
Use the modulo operator to translate the counter `pic` to a [0...count] range. Iterate over the database file and use the counter `pic` and the modulo as needed.

The first part is just to create a test environment, you don't need it, because you already have the environment.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM create test environment
for %%a in (Alpha Beta Gamma Delta Epsilon Zeta Eta Theta Iota Kappa) do break>"%%a.jpg"
>db.csv (for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do @echo !random!)
REM end of creating environment

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM enumerate jpg files
set "count=0"
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (    REM enumerating in alphabetical order
  set "file!count!=%%a"
  set /a count+=1
)

REM associate files
set "pic=0"
for /f %%a in (db.csv) do (
  set /a "n=pic %% count"
  set /a "pic+=1"
  call echo copy "%%file!n!%%" "pic!pic!-%%a.jpg"
  REM or whatever you really want to do with it...
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Really learned from this, appreciate the elegance of the solution.